# Button backcolor not changing upon mousehover

Tags: c#, winforms, button, colors

I have a button that I want to remain transparent (because the background is an image that has all of the buttons pre-designed). To make this work, I have put the following code in the button's MouseEnter and MouseHover events:

```
btnOpen.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

However, upon running the program nothing has changed. When the cursor enters the button, it's backColor is still gray. How could I fix this?

Comment: Could you show more context and mention what platform you are using?

Comment: What is the Parent of that Button? The *transparency* feature is tied to a Control's Parent.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm using WinForms

Comment: @Jimi The button's parent is the form itself.

Comment: Then what you see is Parent's background. Change the Button's Parent (and reposition it, since also the Location is relative to the Parent).

Comment: Try this if you haven't.  It will will let you understand Form transparency better. 
 Put a Button partially overlapping your PictureBox, and set these properties:  `this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta; this.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
this.button1.BackColor = Color.Magenta;`  You'll see how transparency is implemented at the _form_ level.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you, pretty insightful. I've figured it out though. I just had to set `MouseDownBackColor` and `MouseOverBackColor` to transparent.